# Choose puppet template depending on the classes installed on one machine

Tags: class, templates, tomcat, configuration, puppet

We're using Puppet to provision Tomcat7 Resources to a context.xml file for web archives.

We have three archives, each one needs a distinct set of resource entries in the context.xml. Using a template and filling in the right ones by artifact is easy as long as we have one artifact per tomcat instance.

But we also have the scenario where all three artifacts are installed into one tomcat instance (for testing stages). In this case we need *all* resource entries for the three artifacts at the same time.

Two solutions come to mind, both are not really satisfying to me:

1. Stop using templates and use augeas lenses to edit the file.
   Con: context.xml is XML and augeas usage is error-prone and largely unreadable.
2. Remove the template-copying part from the artifact's classes and factor is out into a subclass like artifact::supply-context (which supplies the correct configuration for a single artifact). Also supply a class all_artifacts::supply-context (which supplies the configuration for all the contexts).
   Con: Usage of the classes is not transparent anymore. One artifact: "include artifactA, artifactA::supply-context". All artifacts: "include artifactA, artifactB, artifactC, all_artifacts::supply-context.

Does anyone have a better solution or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes into my mind after looking at this problem is the "concat" module[1]. You could combine it with a template and then concatenate relevant parts together is an order. Other that than, you could write your custom file assembly functionality.

1. https://github.com/ripienaar/puppet-concat